# JAVA Preferences - Empty key issue

Tags: java, preferences

I have the following problem in using java.utils.prefs.Preferences.

I've created a class, named Preferences_utils, having a prefs property, the following constructor

```
public Preferences_utils(){
    prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
}
```

and the method

```
public void setPreference(String key, String value){
    prefs.put(key, value);
}
```

When my application starts, I save some key-value information by using Preferences. For example, in the MyAppMainClass.java:

```
Preferences_utils prefs = new Preferences_utils();
prefs.setPreference("test", "hello");
```

My app works fine and everything is ok.
Trying get the "test" key returns "hello" successfully.

Then, I keep my app ON all night long (no tasks are performed).
But, it seems the key is no longer present in the preferences: the default "empty" value is returned.

Am I using the Preferences in the right way?
Anyone could suggest me where is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to export the prefs to XML and reload later, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#exportSubtree(java.io.OutputStream)

Comment: Does it work when you call [sync()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#sync--)?

Comment: @RC. So, when I save a new key-value pair I have to export the prefs? And each time I need a key I have to reload the xml?

Comment: @TmTron Where does the sync() call need to be put?

Comment: after the `setPreference()` call

Comment: @TmTron I was thinking..... If I run two instances of my app on the same machine and I changed a preference for one instance, which value will the other one read? All the instances wil read the last value? Or two different instances will read different values? I think the issue could be this one

Comment: All the answers are in the javadocs of the Preferences class and the [sync()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#sync--) method.